# what does "how much like them we are" mean?

Tags: expressions

When I ran across the movie,
I found that I can't understand it.

what does "how much like them we are" mean?

Answer (score 1):

It's a sad way of admitting "*We are quite similar to them.*", most likely spoken after some kind of difficult or unfair situation with "them".

Answer (score 0):

In:

> **How** much like them we are.

the definition of [*how*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/how) is:

> 12. used in exclamations to emphasize extent ⇒ *how happy I was!*

It is emphasizing the amount of similarity between "we" and "them".